# asm X86 - segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

**Introduction**

I'm following "ProgrammingGroundUp" book. and I've followed the example of creating a function to raise the power of two numbers and adding them. "2^3 + 5^2". However when I go to compile the code, and then run the program. I receive a segmentation fault.

From my understanding a segmentation fault occurs when a program attempts to do an illegal read or write from a memory location. I think it could be occurring inside the function itself, however confused of where the segmentation fault has occurred.

**Source Code - power.s**

```
#purpose illustrate how functions work. Program will compute 2^3 + 5^2
#using registers so nothing in data section
.section .data

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl   $3      #push 2nd arg on stack
pushl   $2      #push 1st arg on stack
call power  

addl    8,%esp      #move stack pointer back
pushl   %eax        #push result to top of stack

pushl   $2      #push 2nd arg on stack
pushl   $5      #push 1st arg on stack
call power

addl    8,%esp      #move stack pointer back

popl %ebx       #put function1 result into ebx reg
addl    %eax , %ebx     #add return result of function2 + function1 result 

movl    $1 , %eax   #exit system call
int $0x80

#PURPOSE: power function
#REGISTERS: %ebx - holds base number ; %ecx - holds power; -4(%ebp) -holds current result ;%eax temp storage

.type   power,@function
power:
pushl   %ebp        #save state of base pointer
movl    %esp,%ebp   #make stack pointer the base pointer
subl    $4,%esp     #room for local storage

movl    8(%ebp),%ebx    #1st arg initialized,
movl    12(%ebp),%ecx   #2nd arg initialized,
movl    %ebx , -4(%ebp) #store current result

power_loop_start:
cmpl    $1,%ecx     #if ^1 then jump to end_power & exit
je  end_power

movl    -4(%ebp),%eax   #store current result
imull   %ebx,%eax   #multiply
movl    %eax,-4(%ebp)   #store result

decl    %ecx            #decrement ecx
jmp power_loop_start    #loop

end_power:          #return
movl    -4(%ebp) , %eax     #move result in eax for return
movl    %ebp , %esp     #reset the stack pointer
popl    %ebp            #reset base pointer to original position
ret             #return
```

**Compiling**

```
as --32 power.s -o power.o
ld -m elf_i386 power.o -o power
./power
```

> Segmentation fault

**Summary**

Segmentation fault occurring in code, Not sure where is exactly, very new to assembly, tried to explain as best I can. BTW used the "--32" as the code is 32bit and I'm on a 64bit machine.

*Also if my question doesn't meet stack overflow standards please let me know so I can improve.

Comment: Just a cursory look. Lines like `addl    8,%esp` are not doing what you want. It should be `addl    $8,%esp` (not the `$` in front to denote an immediate value and not a memory operand)

Comment: *facepalm* you're right. How the hell did i miss that @Michael Petch

Comment: This is probably too late to comment, but the *technical* reason you experienced a segfault is because `ADDL 8, %ESP` accesses a memory address that is out of bounds for your program's segment of memory on your computer. :)

Comment: @mike bayko ye i figured. Thanks for commenting though. I'm absolutely loving learning X86 assembly at the moment,so learning a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Michael Petch for spotting the syntax error. In lines such as "addl 8,%esp" i did not put the dollar sign, which signifies a value and not a memory address as the instruction is immediate addressing. However i miseed the dollar sign which makes it into a memory address. Thanks for helping.